# API for username password keychain dialog in Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, authentication, passwords

Is there an API that we can use that displays the usual username field, password field, and  remember checkbox? This dialog can be usually seen when connecting to a server via Finder or when Safari requests for proxy information.

I am currently implementing this via CFUserNotification API to save myself from creating a window, etc. but I have to specify the fields and checkbox and retrieve them. What would really save time is an API that will abstract developers from having to worry about it. Does such API exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. Actually I don't have an idea why apple should deploy an api for such a small task.

That's only a NSSecureTextField and a NSTextField. There are plenty of classes that help you add a password properly to the keychain.

Comment: How would one use NSSecureTextField and a NSTextField without a NIB?

Comment: You can also display them programmatically?!

Comment: But that would mean having to create an NSWindow, NSView, etc, right? It would more lines of code and I have a feeling thousands of developers all over the world are doing exactly the same, duplicated code just to get the username and password.I think a lot would benefit if this API existed. Will probably file an enhancement radar bug to get this API in.